# Orthodox Jewish Divorce Statistics

Tags: kohen-priest, divorce, statistics, demography

A Kohain may not marry a divorcee. (Vayikra 21:7) I am wondering if anyone ever did statistics of Orthodox Jews and divorce to see if there is a smaller percentage of Kohanim that get divorced relative to a Levi or Yisrael as for a male Kohain it would be even harder to get remarried since he may not marry a divorcee.

Comment: On a related note, there were certain Halachos added to Gittin (Mekushar, I think?) that made the Get process more complex in order to prevent a Kohen from divorcing his wife in a fit of anger, and then not be able to remarry her.

Comment: Are there any ramifications of this that pertain to Judaism? Otherwise it seems off topic.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Get Koreiach. Mekushar is a thing done to make it a Get Koreiach. See the very end of HaZoreik in Gittin.

Comment: Frequency of a certain Mitzva performance in the face of certain potential Issurim is unambiguously on topic.

Comment: According to [The Times of Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/with-jewish-divorce-rates-at-30-ny-orthodoxy-responds/), about 30% of Orthodox Jewish marriages in the U.S. end in divorce. Compare this with the 50% of marriages total in the U.S. which end in divorce, at least according to [here](http://www.apa.org/topics/divorce/).

Comment: I sadly doubt any survey would include a breakdown by *yichus*

Comment: @DoubleAA He's not asking about frequency of mitzvah performance. He's asking if mitzvah performance leads to a frequency (or infrequency) of something else.

Comment: @alex what's the something else?

Comment: @DoubleAA  Divorce.

Comment: @Alex That's number 579

Comment: @DoubleAA I knew you were going to go there. But he is clearly not asking about divorce as a mitzvah. He is asking a sociological question about whether certain types of Jews are less prone to divorce. If the question was whether hot-tempered Jews divorce more frequently would that be on topic because divorce is a "mitzvah"? The reason why I would think this question might be on topic is that it is based on underlying halachic issues. But I would still think that the question should have some relevance to the issues themselves.

Comment: @DoubleAA By the way, I think [this meta post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope) is very relevant. I don't know that a real consensus was ever reached.